# Search for particular words of a query in mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

How to search for particular keywords in the string from the database!

I don't want to do it by splitting the string into array of words and use the OR keyword in the where clause! Any other methods to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `like` keyword in your request to search word or other regular expression. For example, request:

```
select some_string from haystack where some_string like '%needle%'
```

will return strings containse 'needle' as substring

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use "Locate" keyword of mysql.

you can read more about on it from below link:

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-locate-function.php

mysql's find_in_set function is also very useful. But i think in your case, LOCATE() function is very much suitable for string.